# Why does page refresh when i click search?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am trying to build a program that would help me add products to a particular website, so for this, the products (already fed into the database) are being called using jsp (I have used a custom bean that would handle all connections etc.).

So far I have had the whole list of products be displayed on the screen when the page loads.

I used a mix of javascript and jsp when the search button is clicked (I know jsp is server side and javascript client, but here's what happens).

When i click the search button, for around a millisecond i can see that the search has displayed the correct result, but then the page refreshes immediately, and displays the whole list again, i have also inspected the code on the browser, and it shows that the result is being processed by the javascript function, but isn't being displayed..

Here's my code (excuse the bad programming technique, i'm new to this)

```
<jsp:useBean id="Etn" scope="session" class="com.etn.beans.Contexte" />
<%@page import="com.etn.lang.ResultSet.Set" %>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader" %>
<%@page import="java.io.IOException" %>     
<%@page import="java.io.InputStreamReader" %> 
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Product selection</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="   <%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/bootstrap__portal__.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/font-awesome.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/common.js"></script>
    enter code here<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <script>
    function function1(){
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML =     
    "<% 
    String abc=request.getParameter("s1");
    if(abc==null){}
    else{
    Set rs2 = Etn.execute("select * from products where id = '"+abc+"'");
        if(rs2.next()){

        out.write(rs2.value("id")+" ");
        out.write (rs2.value("image_name")+"<br>");
        out.write(rs2.value("image_actual_name")+" ");
        out.write
    (rs2.value("product_type")+"<br><br>");
        }  

   }
     %>";

 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
       <div class ="container">
           <center><h2> Search Product </h2></center>
    <form action="index.jsp">  
    <br><br>
    <div class ="col-sm-4">
    <label> Search By ID </label>
    <br>
    <input name ="s1" id="e1" type ="text" class ="input-lg"/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="function1();">Search</button>
    <br>
    </div>
    </form>

    <div id="div1">   
      <%
        Set rs = Etn.execute("select * from products");
        while(rs.next()){
            %><div><%
        out.write(rs.value("id")+" ");
        out.write (rs.value("image_name")+"<br>");
        out.write(rs.value("image_actual_name")+" ");
        out.write(rs.value("product_type")+"<br><br>");
        }

      %>    
     </div>    
     </div>
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is a submit button in a form and that is what submit buttons do.

You can `return false` from the onclick function to stop the normal behaviour of the submit button (i.e. submitting the form).

In the sprit of [unobtrusive JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) you should make the server side code be handle to handle the form submission correctly [when the JS fails](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `button` is submitting the form and therefore triggering a new request, which reloads the page. You could either add `type='button'` to the button or `return false` from your `function1()`